# How should Urls from User Options be matched in Content_Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension that has options which let users decide which sites they want the extension to run on.

Say the user has this site in the options

```
site                          action
stackoverflow.com/*           change background css to blue
google.com/*                  change background css to green
```

I store these string in the options. When the content_script runs should I retrieve these strings from options, loop through each one, parse with a urlParser into parts, turn each part into a regex (escaping everything but *), and compare it with document.URL? I recently read that this kind of user options validation for Urls should be done through a background script too so I'm not sure which way to go or if there's a more obvious way to do it.

I think extensions like Adblocker and Vimium seem to have this functionality but for deciding which sites **not** to run on. I want to figure out how to decide which sites **to** run on.

**Update to the Question:** Since my content_script needs to run at document_start (before the page is loaded since it deals with editting the page appearance) as a content_script, will the background page be able to execute the content_script **before** the webpage is loaded at all?

Answer (score 0):

Validated a web page's url should be "validated" via a background page because the user's options will be hosted in local storage in the context of the background page. Here is what I would do... (although it's more of a suggestion that an answer).

I am not sure how the actions on the right column of your list factor into your question, sorry.

(Also note, you would need to incorporate a library (external or self-written) that can parse globs into regex.)

**manifest.json**

```
permissions: ["tabs", "storage", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"]
```

**background.js**

```
//allow the webrequest to run on all urls
var filter = { urls: "<all_urls>" };

//receives url information from webrequest listener
function listen(details) {
    getUserOpts()
        .then(function(arrayOfWhitelistUrls) {
            //you can't use globs here, need to use more powerful filtering mechanisms
            if (arrayOfWhitelistUrls.indexOf(details.url) > -1) {
                message();
            }
        });
}

//returns a promise containing user defined whitelist urls from background local storage
function getUserOpts() {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        chrome.storage.get("whitelist", function(data) {
            //you are saving all localhost data as a string, so you need to parse it first
            res(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
}

//messages content script and allows execution
function message() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {permission: true});
    });
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(listen, filter)
```

**contentscript.js**

```
function listen(message) {        
    if (message.permission) {
        if (message.permission === true) {
            init();
        }
    }
}

//listen for message
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addEventListener(listen);
```

So the order in which things run is like:

- 1. background page listens to each web request
- 2. on each web request, the background page asynchronously fetches user options from local storage
- 3. if the url of the current tab passes your filter, message your content script
- 4. the content script receives the message and then runs

There might be an easier way to do this; the downside to this method is that you need to include the permission gateway in every content script you have.

Comment: You can instead call chrome.tabs.executeScript in the background page to run the content_script.
The actions part was just an example, I hope to do more complicated things than change css. My main concern is the User whitelist so for now it seems like a background page is a good idea to not load the entire content_script until it's needed I see

Comment: @user2807904 that's probably a better solution

Comment: actually I'm not sure if the background page + content_script call will finish running before the page is loaded. Right now my content_script is run at document_start so the javascript finishes running before the page is even loaded. (if you put a breakpoint in the content_script, the browser is completely white with nothing loaded. Would the same for the background script or would the html load while the background.js is running?